# How to save images inside assets folder at runtime in grails 3 app?

Tags: grails, file-upload, asset-pipeline

In my grails app i need to upload and image and render the same image in my view. 
I could upload the image files only inside src/main/webapp directory by following code :

```
def webrootDir = servletContext.getRealPath("/") //app directory
    String imageDestination = webrootDir + params.id;
    if(image){
        File uploadedImage = new File(webrootDir,"${params.id}");
        println "uploadedImage = ${uploadedImage.getAbsoluteFile()}"
        if(uploadedImage?.exists()){
            uploadedImage.delete()
        }
        image.transferTo(uploadedImage);}
```

But i couldn't render the image from this location in `<img>` tag. 
Is there any way to put files inside assets directory while uploading, or is there any way to render from src/main/webapp directory?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I would upload and serve these images from somewhere *outside* of your app. For example, upload the images to S3 (or similar) and make them publicly accessible so that you can still refer to them within your app. Either keep track of the image URLs in a database or use a convention that will allow you to build the image URLs within your app.

You could also use a directory on your server to store the images and then make them publicly accessible somehow. You could [serve them via Tomcat using a different context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908653/configuring-a-tomcat-webapp-to-serve-static-content-from-external-directory#16910319) or use Apache to direct requests either to your app or to serve images directly.

Hope that makes sense.